# Calling an internal "function" in CMD script not updating the variable

Tags: function, batch-file, cmd

In this NT cmd shell\"batch file" I scrabbled together the other day, I'm using the [call](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) command to [run sections of the script like functions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html)--as I have done many times before in other scripts. But one of this is behaving strange and I can't figure out what might be wrong...

The problem is that the first time the function is called it properly returns the errorcode and sets the (global) variable `%RESULT%`, but every time it's called again later it fails to update the variable with the new errorcode.

Here's a stripped-down version of the code in question:

```
:FACL
REM run fileacl.exe with given OPTIONS (%1)
REM uses global variables %TARGET% and %LOGPATH%, sets global %RESULT%
setlocal
set _OPTIONS_=%*
fileacl.exe "%TARGET%" %_OPTIONS_% /SILENT >%LOGPATH%\temp.out 2>%LOGPATH%\temp.err
set _RESULT_=%ERRORLEVEL%
if defined DEBUG echo INSIDE FUNCTION: _RESULT_ = %_RESULT_%
endlocal & set RESULT=%_RESULT_% & goto :EOF
```

The function is called in lines like this:

```
call :FACL /LINE
if defined DEBUG echo AFTER TEST #1: RESULT = %RESULT%
...
call :FACL /INHERIT /REPLACE /FORCE
if defined DEBUG echo AFTER FIX #2: RESULT = %RESULT%
```

You see those `if defined DEBUG...` lines there? They show me that inside the function, subsequent calls are succeeding and thus printing out the expected `%_RESULT_%` of 0, but the global `%RESULT%` remains the same. Here's some example output:

```
TEST #1:
INSIDE FUNCTION: _RESULT_ = 107  <-- that's what I expect for the first call
AFTER TEST #1: RESULT = 107      <-- the variable was properly set after the first call

FIX #2:
INSIDE FUNCTION: _RESULT_ = 0    <-- command succeeded :)
AFTER FIX #2: RESULT = 107       <-- variable didn't change :(

RETEST:
INSIDE FUNCTION: _RESULT_ = 0    <-- succeeded again
AFTER RETEST: RESULT = 107       <-- still didn't change
```

You may ask: what else have you tried? Okay:

1. Removed the `setlocal\endlocal` tricks and just used the global `%RESULT%` variable
2. Explicitly undefined `%RESULT%` and `%_RESULT_%` (e.g. `set RESULT=`) before each time the function is called

...all with the same results. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: I used [this script](http://ideone.com/eEv7N) to reproduce something similar to what is happening in yours, and the results were unlike your results, i.e. they were different each time, like I expected. By the way, do you realise that you are storing an extra space after `%_RESULT_%` on the `endlocal` line? I'm not sure if that can have anything to do with your present issue, just letting you know.

Comment: Good eye on the extra space! I solved that by using `SET /A RESULT=...` to ensure that the stored value is a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't be sure, because we can't see the actual code in context. But the behavior you are describing is to be expected if the FIX 2 CALL and ECHO are within a parenthesized block - perhaps as part of an IF statement or FOR loop.

If that is the case, then you need to use delayed expansion within the parentheses since the entire block is parsed prior to execution and the %RESULT% is expanded at parse time.

Use `SET EnableDelayedExpansion` to enable delayed expansion, and use `!RESULT!` instead of `%RESULT%` to get the value of RESULT at execution time instead of at parse time.

Comment: dbenham, you are *exactly* right: the subsequent "function" calls are all inside a parenthesized IF block! I often use the delayed expansion, but hadn't thought of that applying here.